# VBA How to work with global arrays- it doesn't return data from function

Tags: arrays, vba, function, global

I've got a global array - I declare it in declarations

```
    Public iPick1() As Variant
    Public count6 as Long 
    Sub MainMacro()
    for i=1 to count2
    If <something> Then 
    count6=count6+1
    '....some code 
    call AddiPick1(i) 'here I call a function to add the array 
    End If
    next i 
For a=1 To count6
Rows(iPick1(a)).Delete'here is an error 
Next a
    End Sub
```

and a function, adding data in the array

```
Function AddiPick1(ByVal ln As Integer)
Dim mark As Integer, u As Long

mark = 0
For u = 1 To count6
If iPick1(u) = ln Then mark = 1
Next u
If mark = 0 Then
count6 = count6 + 1
ReDim Preserve iPick1(count6)
iPick1(count6) = ln
End If
AddiPick1 = iPick1
End Function
```

But the array is out of range. What's wrong?

Comment: How is count6 defined?

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket too

Comment: countt6 is also a public variable counting in main macro. I've checked - Redim in function is OK, but after function array is unavailable

Comment: it's not an erro in bracket - full code is very large - I've just copied a part

Comment: I think you should post a better example with the relevant code showing, as not to waste time.

Comment: Are you sure you will read a full code? :) It's a complex of over 10 modules.  Then you will understand all.  The problem is that I redim global array in function and after return from function array isn't changed

Comment: Not the full code, the definitiion, types where used, what the error is etc.

Comment: I write for the third time - I declare public array, then I  redim it and fill with values in the function and after function is over array is empty

Comment: In `iPick1` you do this `count6=count6+1`  then you do it again in `AddiPick1` - are you leaving gaps in your array?  That would explain why `Rows(iPick1(a)).Delete` fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't understood why  can't I change public array in any sub or function directly - because global array and variables are made just for this.
If anybody can explain me why direct change works with global variables and I failed with the global array - please answer.

But I've got a method to change the array in function and return it to sub.
Need just to send array as argument `byRef` to function like this

```
Public test()
Public c
Sub testarray()
For i = 1 To 5
c = c + 1
Call test1(test)
Debug.Print test(i)
Next i
End Sub

Function test1(ByRef test)
ReDim Preserve test(c)
test(c) = c
End Function
```

Comment: Your function isn't s function, its a sub, as you do not return any value.

Comment: in this case it doesn't matter- it works. Sometimes it's better call subs as functions to divide them from main subs.